# Adding new (non-reusable) cells for every row in UItableview swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios9

I have `UIWebView` in most of the cell of `UITableView`, which are using to show  Video.
In most on cases number of cells will be less but these could be endless. On scrolling the `UITableView`; webView reload its data every time.

Can anyone have solution how to create new cell for every row instead of using **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** to prevent reloading in UIWebView.

---

I still don't prefer to create new cell every time.
But then **how to prevent webView reloading every time?**

Comment: Can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath so I can easily show you how to address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary with NSIndexPath as key and UITableViewCell as value

```
// MARK: - Properties

private var cells: [NSIndexPath: VideoCell] = [:]
private var videos: [Video] = []

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cachedCell = self.cells[indexPath] {
        return cachedCell
    }
    else {
            let videoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(VideoCell.ReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCell
            videoCell.bindWith(self.videos[indexPath])
            self.cells[indexPath] = videoCell
            return videoCell
        }
    }

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let videoCell = cell as? VideoCell else {
        return
    }
    videoCell.refresh()
}
```

If you will have a lot of cell you may face up with memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reuse the cell and reload the webview in the cell if you consider the efficiency and performance, just reload the one which has never been played, and at the same time cache the video data or the html data to local. On the other hand, for playing cell, you can record the object of webview, directly setup these webviews to reused cell.

Pseudo code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // If the video at this row is playing, just setup webview
    UIWebView *webView = [self webviewOfPalyingForIndexPath: indexPath];
    if (webView) {
        [cell setupWithWebview: webView];
    } else {
        // Configure cell with reused webview
        static UIWebView *publicWebview = [UIWebView new];
        [cell setupWithWebview: publicWebview];

        // Check if the data of webview is cached
        NSData *cachedData = [self readCachedDataForIndexPath: indexPath];
        if (cachedData) {
            [cell setupWithCachedData:cachedData];
        } else { // If not cached, load url and cach the data
            [cell setupWithUrl: your_url];
            [self cacheDataForUrl: your_url];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

// Record webview of playing at indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self recordPlayingWebView: cell.webview atIndexPath: indexPath];
}
```

Hope my answer is usefull for you.

**UPDATE:**

Pseudo code with Swift:

```
let reusedWebview = UIWebView()
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // If the video at this row is playing, just setup webview
    let webView = self.webviewOfPalyingForIndexPath(indexPath)
    if (webView != nil) {
        cell.setupWithWebview(webView)
    } else {
        // Configure cell with reused webview
        cell.setupWithWebview(resuedWebview)

        // Check if the data of webview is cached
        let cachedData = self.readCachedDataForIndexPath(indexPath)
        if (cachedData != nil) {
            cell.setupWithCachedData(cachedData)
        } else { // If not cached, load url and cach the data
            cell.setupWithUrl(your_url)
            self.cacheDataForUrl(your_url)
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    self.recordPlayingWebView(cell.webview, forIndexPath: indexpath)
}
```